# Angular app don't show $scope values, not error message

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

i'm learning MEAN stack, and trying to build an app based on demoof this course (thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial#creating-schemas-with-mongoose).
I checked that's there is on db with curl, it's ok, but angular dont bind them.

--> This is the view (index.ejs) :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>demo</title>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/angularApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="demo">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <ui-view></ui-view>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
    <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Patients : </h1>
  </div>

    <div ng-repeat="patient in patients">
        <a>{{patient.name}} - Nom: {{patient.surname}} - Age: {{patient.old}}</a>
    </div>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

--> This is my node js code (index.js)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Patient = mongoose.model('Patient');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

/* GET all patients */
router.get('/patients', function(req, res, next){
    Patient.find(function(err, patients){
        if(err){ return next(err); }

        res.json(patients);
    });
});

//configure express : retrieve automatically post by id
router.param('patient', function(req, res, next, id){
    var query = Patient.findById(id);

    query.exec(function(err, patient){
        if(err){ return next(err); }
        if(!patient){ return next(new Error("Aucun patient dans la base...")); }

        req.patient = patient;
        return next();
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

--> And this is my angular code (angularApp.js)

```
var app = angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router']);

app.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: '/home.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
                        return posts.getAll();
                    }]
                }
            });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
    }]);

app.factory('posts', ['$http', function($http){
    var o = {
        posts: []
    };

    o.getAll = function() {
        return $http.get('/posts').success(function(data){
            angular.copy(data, o.posts);
        });
    };

    return o;
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope',
'posts',
function($scope, posts){
    $scope.posts = posts.posts;
}]);
```

Comment: Please first find where it goes wrong. Is it the fetching of the data? is it the binding to the scope? Is it the displaying of the values? You can check by doing some `console.log(data)`

Comment: I think it's binding to the scope, because fetching data it's ok if i reach /patients, it's returning all my customers as json format. I tried to pu some console(data), but i'm using a logger, "morgan" in express, and it don't show every console message.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't bind the controller "MainCtrl" in your html

Comment: It's because he uses state routing

Comment: yes effectivelly, in the tutorial they don't bind MainCtrl controller in view because they use ui-router module, controller is declared in the state 'home' in app.config().

Comment: This is a clone of code explained in thinkster.io tutorial : https://github.com/jermspeaks/Thinkster-MEAN-Tutorial/blob/master/views/index.ejs